# Как не применять условие в SQL если оно не пришло?

Tags: php, sql

Нужно вывести список товаров, применив фильтры.

```sql
SELECT `goods`.`id`
    , `goods`.`name`
    , `ratingGoods`.`assessment`
    , `goods`.`description`
    , `remnats`.`sale_price` 
FROM `remnats` 
    LEFT JOIN `goods` ON `goods`.`id` = `remnats`.`id_tovar` 
    LEFT JOIN `ratingGoods` ON `ratingGoods`.`goodsId` = `goods`.`id` 
    LEFT JOIN `accounting` ON `accounting`.`goods_id` = `remnats`.`id_tovar`
    LEFT JOIN `sales` ON `sales`.`accouting_id` = `accounting`.`id` 
WHERE (`goods`.`category_id` = '.$_POST['category'].') 
GROUP BY `goods`.`id` 
ORDER BY SUM(`sales`.`number`) 
DESC LIMIT '.$_POST['limit'].';
```

Как вставить все условия, но так чтобы когда переменная пуста, то sql пропускал это условие и выводились все значения этого поля?
Или всё таки придётся делать большое количество вариантов запросов?

Comment: Собирайте запрос на сервере по факту, в чем проблема? `if( isFlag ) sql += "'goods'.'category_id' = '.$_POST['category'].'`. Если параметр не пришел, он просто не будет включен в результирующую sql-строку для запроса.

Comment: Какая переменная?

Comment: Да я и собираю SQL строку, просто интересно есть ли другой способ

Comment: Doctrine? https://www.doctrine-project.org или https://github.com/nilportugues/php-sql-query-builder

Comment: перед отправкой фильтры собирайте в какой-то массив, `$filters`, к примеру, и потом на сервере через foreach проходитесь и добавляяете where нужные в запрос, и будет что-то типа этого: `foreach($filters as $filter){ $where .= $pre . $filter['name'] . " = " .$filter['value']; $pre = " AND "; }` а потом уже сам запрос в конце собираете, аля `$query = $select.$from.$join.$where.$search.$order.$limit`